# assigning image to uiimageview in table cell

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an image View in custom table cell, and I need to assign it a picture from table view delegate

```
  cell.imageViewLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fxObject.thumbnailName]];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", [UIImage imageNamed:fxObject.thumbnailName],  cell.imageViewLeft.image);
```

The log is giving me:

`<UIImage: 0xb485310>, (null)`

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the `@property` in your custom cell's `.h` file for the image view is `strong` instead of `weak`?

Comment: Yes, `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageViewLeft;
`

Comment: Are you doing anything with the imageView afterward, like adding it to the cell view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to initilize the properties.

```
- (UIImageView *)imageViewLeft {
if (!_imageViewLeft) {
    _imageViewLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _imageViewLeft.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _imageViewLeft.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_imageViewLeft];
}
return _imageViewLeft;
}

- (UIImageView *)imageViewRight {
if (!_imageViewRight) {
    _imageViewRight = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    _imageViewRight.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _imageViewRight.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_imageViewRight];
}
return _imageViewRight;
}
```

Everything else stays same. I believe thats the correct way to initialize views if we are working without NIB files and if we are not making IBOutlet properties.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `IBOutlets` are connected correctly.

Additionally, make sure you @`synthesize` your `imageViewLeft`!

```
cell.imageViewLeft.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fxObject.thumbnailName];
```

Comment: `@synthesize` is depreciated in the Xcode 4.2+. It's done automatically.

Comment: I thought so too. But synthesizing a property just creates getter and setter methods. And its no longer required (Though I don't think its deprecated). A coworker helped me figure this out. I needed to define the properties as I'm doing this all without nib files. I'll answer this question myself in a few mins